# Blocks stopped showing on views page

Tags: blocks

I was hoping you could help me with this problem on my website.

I have a views page "News" for a long time now. (q?=news) 
I also have 2 blocks that I want to show on that page. On the configurations I set: All pages except those listed - and I listed all the pages i don't want the block to show (So I **didn't** write the News page).

Thing is, **this was working fine** and suddendly the blocks stopped showing on that specific page, and I have no idea why.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I can't just try the "Only the listed pages" option because there are too many pages involved.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer because I don't have enough information on what is happening, but here are some suggestions:

1. Give your views page a url alias of /news if you haven't already and in the block configuration make sure "news" is not listed there. Then you don't have to use "?q="
2. Make sure your spelling is correct so it's not q?=news and is ?q=news in your block configuration.
3. Views pages are not great to work with, personally I don't like them for a number of reasons. Instead, I use the insert_block module and I insert a views_block into my node, I get less problems like that and more flexibility.
4. The context module is also a good module for placing blocks in regions based on any type of page, but it's more difficult to manage.

EDIT: More things to check:

5. Make sure no styling is hiding those blocks. Check the markup loaded on the page and see if the markup for those blocks is loading on the page or not.
6. Make sure that the region you assigned those blocks to is actually loading on the views page.